# Is it possible to compile the Linux-Libre kernel without LILO?

Tags: linux, compiling, linux-libre

I'd like to compile/install the Linux-Libre kernel but I don't want to use LILO as a bootloader since I already have GRUB, is it possible to do?

Comment: The bootloader boots the kernels in its configuration file, it isn't fussy about the type of kernel...

Comment: Yeah, but the make install breaks if it doesn't find LILO.

Comment: Then remove that dependency from the makefile. Or, better yet, use the AUR [PKGBUILD which doesn't have that dependency](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-libre)...